# Modeling DW staging from JSON

Tags: data-warehouse, restful-architecture, staging, staging-table

I am building a DW. The sources are comming from rest API that returns Json. I need to design a staging area. I think I have 2 approaches:
1. Transform Json into a relational model. 
2. Store the Json into a relational table using a key value. The key is going to be a field that I will use to performs join. The value is going to be the Json.

The first one is a by the book approach but I think it's harder to maintain. The second one is easier to maintain, but complicated to do complex queries.

Which are the drawbacks from each solution? Opinions are accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Approach 1 is good for Data warehouse and second approach fits on Data lake scenario .

JSON - Jtore whole details intact to one document, We will be storing key unnecessary (increase size of data base performance hit) for each document , it will complicated /performance hit query where result recurred cross doc which is a common in DW scenarion ..